# Please Check This Translation

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

This is not a mathematics problem, but is related to mathematics. I am studying an old article by Gahler and it is written in German. Since I do not know German I tried google translate. But I am not so sure about the result. So I am showing you both the German and English versions. Please have look and tell me if any correction is needed.
The German version is:
[image: german]
My translation is:
Let $L$ be a linear $2$-normed space with dimension >1. Then $L$ satisfies Property K if and only if for each $a^*,b^*\in L$ with $\|a^*,b^*\|\neq 0$ the topology of the $1$-norm defined as $$\|a\|=\|a^*,a\|+\|b^*,a\|$$ coincides with the topology of $2$-normed space.

Comment: i think your Translation is correct

Comment: It is not so clear if "verträglich" really means that the topologies coincide. The literal translation is "compatible".